# Flutter, Using null safety - beta vs stable channel

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm learning about the new null safety in dart. What I understand is that it's only working when I'm on the dart channel beta, but when I'm on the stable version it doesn't work. Meaning the terms: `?` and `!`, and `late`, etc, when I'm on the stable version, causes errors in my code. It only works if I'm on the beta version.

Is this OK that all my code will only be working on the beta version? When I want to publish my app, etc, is this OK that it's written in the beta version, not the stable version?

Comment: I strongly recommend to use the stable channel to publish the app.

Comment: But I'm writting tons of code will null safety, I'll have to change it all?! Am I not supposed to be writing using this?

Comment: Beta channel is recommend to ensure the upcoming update on your application and not from publishing. Beta channel code are not assured to include it upcoming release.

Comment: Always be clear to work on the stable channel.

Comment: So why are they encouraging null safety so much, if I shouldn't publish my code with it?

Comment: They're pushing null safety so that *packages* can be migrated as soon as possible, and then when the null safety features are no longer in beta, null-safe packages will be available to use.

Comment: When you say "null safety features are no longer in beta", you mean because then they will in the stable channel?

Comment: I mean that the Dart SDK that enables non-nullable-by-default is in beta (2.12.0).  The latest stable version of the Dart SDK is 2.10.

Comment: Sorry to continue to ask, I just cannot settle this. Is null safety a thing I should start using as standard now I'm starting with dart, or not? Is this going to be the way forward so I should use it, or may it not take off with dart. Thanks!!

Comment: If you're writing a package that you intend to share to pub.dev, you should make a null-safe version of the package.  For application code, it probably will be easier if you wait until null-safety is enabled in stable versions of the Dart and Flutter SDKs.  Also see https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide.  In the meantime, you can add `/*?*/` and `/*!*/` hints to your code to make migration easier later.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels#which-channel-should-i-use) :

We recommend using the stable branch.

That said, the beta branch should be fine. There is no extra level of testing that we do for stable than for beta, other than the extended stabilization period on the beta branch. So if there is something you want to use that is available on beta but not stable, feel free to consider using the beta.

EDIT: But it's recommended to publish your app in the stable version, but if you are in a hurry and can't wait for the next update then from the documentation I think you can do the publish